# Find IonCube PHP files

Tags: php, ioncube

The pSek server hosting company installed 54 PHP extensions for no reason, and while going through the list of unneeded extensions I noticed IonCube, which I want to get rid of quickly. What's a good way to find out if we have any PHP files encrypted with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't encrypted them yourself, then you won't have any encrypted files, but IonCube encrypted files should have `if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader'))` somewhere near the top of every file.